# Type pararmeter as the data/value constructor

Tags: haskell

Reading through `Numeric.LinearProgramming` I am confused by the type declaration

```
data Bound x =   x :<=: Double 
               | x :>=: Double
               | x :&: (Double, Double)
               | x :==: Double
               | Free x 
                   deriving Show
```

Suppose we input `Int` in place of `x`. Then a member of type Bound Int would be something like `Int :&: (1.2345 :: Double)`. But `Int` is a type, and presumably not a valid name/identifier for a data constructor. What's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

In this example, `x` is not the data constructor, rather `:&:`, `:<=:`, `:>=:`, `:==:`, and `Free`. Apart from `Free`, these are all [infix data constructors](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2018/course/TDA555/FAQ.html#infix-data-constructors). The best-known example is the list 'append' operator, `:`.

Comment: `:` is traditionally called "cons", while "append" is a name typically given to `++` which operates between two lists.